# How to save a Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/docker-networking-rules/, which contains the following:

[image]

As I understand it, the code

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Laura Frank <laura.frank@centurylink.com>
CMD while true; do echo 'hello world' | nc -l -p 8888; done
```

Is the content of a `Dockerfile`, which can be put in a newly created, empty directory and build using the command `docker build .`.

I don't quite understand however how to 'name' the image `no-exposed-ports`? Am I supposed to use tagging (the `-t` option) as in the example in https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that by 'naming' the Docker image it is indeed meant that you use a tag. I used the command

```
docker build -t no-exposed-ports .
```

which gives the following response:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:trusty
 ---> 3f755ca42730
Step 2 : CMD while true; do echo 'hello world' | nc -l -p 8888; done
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8a7551d0ed9
Successfully built b8a7551d0ed9
```

From the command `docker images` I can see that `no-exposed-ports` is the name of the `REPOSITORY`, and the default tag `latest` has been assigned:

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
no-exposed-ports                 latest              b8a7551d0ed9        18 minutes ago      188 MB
```

Finally, running with the command

```
docker run -d --name no-exposed-ports no-exposed-ports
```

produces a long hash as in the example on the blog:

```
eb39d8ef68826510f4c964ad586ff04b9e334433538d9d69a39aa0ec44d6701f
```